# PYQT5 Gui crashes sometimes when I start a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

Like I said in the hedding, my programm crashes sometimes when I start the following thread. I don't get any Error, It just closes sometimes...
If it crashes, then it crashes in the first round of the while-loop.
I think its because of the time.sleep(0.5) because everything before this line works perfectly fine.
My complete Programm runs perfectly fine, its just this part here which gives me a headache:

```py
    def TimeClock(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        TimeThreadRunning = True
        Datum = datetime.now()
        self.ui.label_3.setText(Datum.strftime("%H : %M"))
        while TimeThreadRunning == True:
            print("Uhrzeit wird überprüft")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            Datum = datetime.now()
            self.ui.label.setText(_translate("GUI", Datum.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")))
            self.ui.label_2.setText(_translate("GUI", Datum.strftime("%H : %M")))

    TimeTread = threading.Thread(target=TimeClock, args=(self,))
    TimeTread.daemon = True
    TimeTread.start()
```

Hope somebody can help. Greetingsfrom Germany

Comment: try this `TimeTread = threading.Thread(target=TimeClock, args=(self,))
TimeTread.start()`

Comment: Qt does not support GUI operations of any kind outside the main thread. Use a QThread instead, and send updates to the main thread via signals (which are thread-safe).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll try if that works